# How to access the ConnectSDK Cordova Plugin on Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I'm using the [ConnectSDK cordova plugin](https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Cordova-Plugin) in a Capacitor React app to add a screen cast feature but I wasn't able to access the plugin and its functions. I've installed the plugin by this command only, as there are no wrappers from ionic-native:

`npm i cordova-plugin-connectsdk --legacy-peer-deps`

I've attempted to access it by the `window` object but it's not available there or any of its members, trying `(window as any).ConnectSDK` for example returns undefined.

I've also tried configuring the `plugin.xml` according to the [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/plugin_ref/spec.html) but no luck:

```
<js-module src="www/ConnectSDK.js" name="ConnectSDK.js">
  <merges target="navigator.ConnectSDK" />
  <merges target="ConnectSDK" />
  <clobbers target="ConnectSDK" />
</js-module>
```

And using an import declaration returns an `Cannot find module` error:

`import ConnectSDK from 'cordova-plugin-connectsdk'`

Trying to set `declare var cordova: any;` also returns `undefined` for the cordova object.

I'm not sure how to proceed as there are no instructions for use in Capacitor in the [connectsdk cordova docs](https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Cordova-Plugin) or anywhere else. What else could I try here?